# How to show mathematically that probability distribution of a word vector is better than another

Tags: probability, word2vec, latent-dirichlet-alloc

I an newbie to the statistics and probability. I have been working on Latent Dirichlet Allocation - Topic Coherence Optimization. As a part of my research work, I have two word vectors, say V1 and V2. I have also a reference corpus with hundreds of documents. The Vector V1 is a topic with set of words. Similarly, Vector V2 with set of words but It has got more occurrences in reference corpus compare to V1. I want to show that V2 has higher NPMI/PMI score than V1. How do I represents with more mathematical (Statistical) terms and formulas?